# Unable to get dropdown selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is populated with a dropdown list on each row. The DDL is populated with a number from 1 - how ever many rows there are.

I have a save button to save the value of each DDL for each row using a simple loop but the problem is that the dropdown never returns the selected value, it seems to return something like the row index of the gridview + 1.

This is an example of how I select the values in the rows:

3
7
4
6
5
2
1

When I do the same, this is how they will save:

2
3
4
5
6
7
1

This is my code from the save, just to let you know I have tried selectedvalue, selectedindex, selecteditem and text, they all do the same.

```
//save the data
            foreach (GridViewRow r in gvOrder.Rows)
            {
                if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    //get the details from the grid
                    Label lblED = r.FindControl("lblED") as Label;
                    DropDownList ddl = r.FindControl("ddlNewO") as DropDownList;
                    TextBox txt = r.FindControl("txtNewT") as TextBox;
                    Label ID = r.FindControl("lblID") as Label;
                    int Order = Convert.ToInt16(ddl.SelectedValue);
                    string Text = "";
                    if (txt.Text != "")
                    {
                        Text = txt.Text;
                    }
                    //save each row to the db

                    try
                    {
                        SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection();
                        dbConnection.ConnectionString = GetConnection.GetConnectionString();
                        SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("PL_UserColumns_Save", dbConnection);
                        dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@PageID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(constPageID);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(strUserID);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@Order", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(Order);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ColumnID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(ID.Text);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ED", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(lblED.Text);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "'" + Text + "'";
                        dbConnection.Open();
                        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dbConnection.Close();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        ExceptionHandling.SQLException(ex, constPageID, constIsSiteSpecific);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: How are you binding the values in the first place?

Comment: It's complicated but they are populated in the rowdatabound and there is one number for each row, so if I have 8 rows, each DDL is populated with 1-8. The selected index is then set to the row index but that's not important.

Comment: @connersz: did you try using 'ddl.SelectedItem.ToString()' in the place of 'ddl.SelectedValue'.?

Answer (score 0):

to get the DropDownList selected value you have to use this:

```
ddl.SelectedItem.Value
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason I get the value 1 coming up twice, it always comes up on the last row save.

Comment: This is the order of the values I selected: 1,3,5,4,6,2. I clicked save and this is how it saved each dropdown in order: 1,3,4,5,6,1

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Request.Form` to get the posted values. Assuming that your drop-down names will increase with each row e.g. ddlNew0, ddlNew1, etc., then you can do this

```
 var value = Request.Form["ddlNew" + rowIndex];
```

Comment: You might need to play around with the debugger to get the right names as they might come through as things like `ctl00_ddlNew5`.

Comment: I just did a test which shows it is not just the row index now, when the numbers selected are like this: 1,3,5,4,6,2 on saving they come out in this order: 1,3,4,5,6,1 which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in two possible ways:

1. Add a bit of JavaScript to populate a hidden field and then grab and separate the values in the back-end
2. Add auto-postback on dropdowns and an `onClick` method. Also pass the item id as argument. Then do the saving bit in the onclick method.

I would prefer the second one.